# Perform math function in 2nd page of Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My question is how to perform math function in page 2. In frame 2, get input from `entry_1` and `entry_2`, press <kbd>ADD</kbd> or <kbd>SUB</kbd> button to perform add or substract function accordingly. Then display the result in `entry_3` with `insert` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

win = Tk()
win.geometry("400x300+10+10")
win.title("Calculator")

second_frame = Frame(win)
second_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=400, height=300)

first_frame = Frame(win)
first_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=400, height=300)

label_0 = Label(first_frame, text="CHOOSE NUMBER OF INPUT",width=30,font=("bold", 12))
label_0.place(x=60,y=50)

Button(first_frame, text='2 inputs',width=10,font=("bold", 10),bg='yellow',fg='black', 
command=lambda:raise_frame(second_frame)).place(x=155,y=150)

Button(second_frame, text="Back to Front Page",width=18,bg='brown',fg='white', 
command=lambda:raise_frame(first_frame)).place(x=20,y=260)

label_1 = Label(second_frame, text="Digit 1",width=10,font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=100, y=50)

entry_1 = Entry(second_frame)
entry_1.place(x=200,y=50)

label_2 = Label(second_frame, text="Digit 2",width=10,font=("bold", 10))
label_2.place(x=100,y=100)
    #RT = get()(second_frame, entry1, entry2.get())

entry_2 = Entry(second_frame)
entry_2.place(x=200,y=100)

label_3 = Label(second_frame, text="Result",font=("bold", 10))
label_3.place(x=100,y=200)

entry_3 = Entry(second_frame)
entry_3.place(x=200,y=200)
RT = (entry_1,get() + entry_2,get())
entry_3.second_frame, insert(END, str(RT))

Button(second_frame, text='ADD',width=10,bg='blue',fg='black').place(x=100,y=150)
#second_frame.entry1, R1 = int(get())

   #entry_2.delete(0,END)
   #R1=int(entry_1.get())
   #R2=int(entry_2.get())
   #RT= R1 + R2
   #entry_3.insert(END, str(RT))

Button(second_frame, text='SUB',width=10,bg='blue',fg='black').place(x=200,y=150)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is "2nd page"? You don't seem to have any pages in your app. This code has many errors, including syntax errors.

Comment: You need to assign callbacks to `ADD` and `SUB` buttons and do the math operation inside the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want to do here is create two functions for adding and subtracting two numbers.

```
def add_two_num(num1, num2):
    total = int(num1) + int(num2)
    return total

def sub_two_num(num1, num2):
    total = int(num1) - int(num2)
    return total
```

Then, add the "command" argument for each button, calling the appropriate function

```
Button(second_frame, text='ADD',width=10,bg='blue',fg='black',
   command=lambda: [
   entry_3.delete(0, END), 
   entry_3.insert(END,add_two_num(entry_1.get(),entry_2.get()))
   ]).place(x=100,y=150)

Button(second_frame, text='ADD',width=10,
   bg='blue',fg='black',command=lambda: [
   entry_3.delete(0, END),
   entry_3.insert(END,add_two_num(entry_1.get(),entry_2.get()))
   ]).place(x=100,y=150)
```

The lambda command first deletes whatever is already in entry_3, and then computes the sum or difference of the two entries, then places the result in entry_3.

Oh, and, you should remove the two lines in your code:
RT = (entry_1,get() + entry_2,get())
entry_3.second_frame, insert(END, str(RT))

They won't be needed now, and caused syntax errors anyway

Comment: Hi Jasper thank you very much for prompt reply. Your code work wonderfully. You are great. Thanks god I got the solution for my coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign callbacks to <kbd>ADD</kbd> and <kbd>SUB</kbd> buttons and do the math operation inside the callbacks:

```py
def do_add():
    entry_3.delete(0, 'end')
    try:
        v1 = float(entry_1.get().strip())
        v2 = float(entry_2.get().strip())
        entry_3.insert('end', v1+v2)
    except ValueError:
        entry_3.insert('end', 'Invalid values')

def do_sub():
    entry_3.delete(0, 'end')
    try:
        v1 = float(entry_1.get().strip())
        v2 = float(entry_2.get().strip())
        entry_3.insert('end', v1-v2)
    except ValueError:
        entry_3.insert('end', 'Invalid values')


Button(second_frame, text='ADD', width=10, bg='blue', fg='black', command=do_add).place(x=100,y=150)
Button(second_frame, text='SUB', width=10, bg='blue', fg='black', command=do_sub).place(x=200,y=150)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply acw1668. 